# D3 data binding [D3js in Action]

Tags: d3.js, data-binding, selection, transition

I'm new to d3.js, and am working my way through the book "D3.js in action". So far I have been able to figure out all the questions I had, but this one I can't completely answer on my own, it seems.

I post the source code from the book here, since it is available on the books website and the authors homepage. This is the bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/raw/186d62271bb3069446b5/

The basis idea of the code is to create a spreadsheet-like layout out of div elements filled with fictious twitter data. Also implemented is a sort function to sort the data by timestamp and reorder the sheet. As well as a function to reestablish the original order.

Here is the code (I left out the part where the table structure is created, except the part where the data is bound):

```
<html>
<...>
<body>
<div id="traditional"> 
</div>
</body>
  <footer>

<script>
d3.json("tweets.json",function(error,data) { createSpreadsheet(data.tweets)});

      function createSpreadsheet(incData) {

        var keyValues = d3.keys(incData[0])

        d3.select("div.table")
        .selectAll("div.datarow")
        .data(incData, function(d) {return d.content})
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "datarow")
        .style("top", function(d,i) {return (40 + (i * 40)) + "px"});

        d3.selectAll("div.datarow")
        .selectAll("div.data")
        .data(function(d) {return d3.entries(d)})
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "data")
        .html(function (d) {return d.value})
        .style("left", function(d,i,j) {return (i * 100) + "px"});

        d3.select("#traditional").insert("button", ".table")
       .on("click", sortSheet).html("sort")
        d3.select("#traditional").insert("button", ".table")
       .on("click", restoreSheet).html("restore")

function sortSheet() {
          var dataset = d3.selectAll("div.datarow").data();
            dataset.sort(function(a,b) {
              var a = new Date(a.timestamp);
              var b = new Date(b.timestamp);
            return a>=b ? 1 : (a<b ? -1 : 0);
            })
            d3.selectAll("div.datarow")
            .data(dataset, function(d) {return d.content})
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .style("top", function(d,i) {return (40 + (i * 40)) + "px"});
        }

        function restoreSheet() {
          d3.selectAll("div.datarow")
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .style("top", function(d,i) {return (40 + (i * 40)) + "px"});
        }
      }
</script>
  </footer>
</html>
```

What I don't fully understand is how sortSheet and restoreSheet work.

This part of sortSheet looks like it rebinds data, but after console logging I think it doesn't actually rebind data to the DOM. Instead it just seems to redraw the div.tablerow elements based on the array index of the sorted array.

But then what purpose does the key-function have?
And why is the transition working? How does it know which old element to put in which new position?

EDIT:
---After some more reading I now know that `selectAll().data()` does indeed return the update selection. Apparenty the already bound data identified by the key function is re-sorted to match the order of the keys in the new dataset? Is that correct?
So the update selection contains the existing `div.datarow` s, but in a new ordering. The `transition()` function works on the new order, drawing the newly ordered `div.datarow` s beginning with index 0 for the first element to determine its position on the page, to index n for the last element. The graphical transition then **somehow** (how? by way of the update selection?) knows where the redrawn `div.datarow` was before and creates the transition-effect.
Is that correct so far?---

```
d3.selectAll("div.datarow")
.data(dataset, function(d) {return d.content}) //why the key function?
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.style("top", function(d,i) {return (40 + (i * 40)) + "px"});
```

And what happens when the original order is restored? Apparently during both operations there is no actual rebinding of data, and the order of the `div.datarow`s in the DOM does not change. So the restore function also redraws the layout based on the array index.
But what kind of selection does the .transition() work on? <s>Is it an update?</s> It is an update.
And why does the drawing using the index result in the old layout? <s>Shouldn't the index of the DOM elements always be 0,1,...,n?</s> I think it is. Apparently the old page layout is redrawn, with the DOM never having changed. But how can the transition() function create the appropriate graphical effect?

```
function restoreSheet() {
d3.selectAll("div.datarow")
.transition()
.duration(2000)
.style("top", function(d,i) {return (40 + (i * 40)) + "px"});
}
```

I have been thinking for hours about this, but I can't find the correct answer I think.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It all becomes clear when you understand where all these functions were called: inside the `json` function, where the data was originally bound. When a button calls the `sortSheet` function, a new array of objects is made and bound to the rows. The transition simply starts with the original order and move the rows according to the new order of the objects inside the array.

> And what happens when the original order is restored?

Now comes the interesting part: `restoreSheet` is called inside the `json` function and has no access to the `dataset` variable. So, the data `restoreSheet` uses is the original data. Then, a transition simply moves the rows according to the order of the objects inside the original array.

I just made a fiddle replicating this: https://jsfiddle.net/k9012vro/2/

Check the code: I have an array with the original data. Then, a button called "sort" creates a new array.

When I click "original" the rectangles move back to the original position. But there is nothing special in that function, no new data being bound:

```
d3.select("#button1").on("click", function(){
    rects.transition()
    .duration(500).attr("x", function(d, i){ return i * 30})
});
```

It moves all the rectangles to the original positions because this function uses the same original `data`.